# Python function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, function, parentheses, chain, unary-function

I came across this Codewars question:

> Your task is to write a higher order function for chaining together a
> list of unary functions. In other words, it should return a function
> that does a left fold on the given functions.
>
> `chained([a,b,c,d])(input)`
>
> Should yield the same result as
>
> `d(c(b(a(input))))`

I don't really care what the answer to the problem is, I can access that on the site.  What I actually need explained to me is the first function, "chained".  I've never seen a function like that with 2 sets of argument in separate parenthesis, so I imagine I'm interpreting it incorrectly..  what does that mean?    Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a function with two sets of parameters, but a function that returns *another* function, executing the functions given as parameters one after the other.

Maybe it's clearer if you separate the line into two lines:

```
f = chained([a,b,c,d]) # call `chained` with functions as parameters
f(input)               # call result of `chained`, which is another function
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the question `chained` is a [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) - it will take one argument - list of functions and will return/yield a function. That function is called by passing one argument - another function, in this case `input`.